# UML Diagram for TypeScript in WebSorm

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, uml, webstorm

I've got the following problem:

I need to deliver a UML diagram from my TypeScript source code. I want to generate the diagram with WebStorm and the UML plugin, as suggested in many answers to other questions.

The problem is, that I get a dependency diagram on file-level, not on class-level. It looks like this:

[image: Current state]

It shows the files and dependencies between the files, but not the classes, which are defined in the files.

Is there any possibility to get a diagram on class level from TypeScript (and TSX) source files? Any suggestions would be helpful, plugins / options for IntelliJ/WebStorm or external tools...

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

No; the only available diagram for TypeScript is a *module dependency diagram* that shows how the modules depend on each other (based on `require()` and `import` statements). There is no way to create a UML Class diagram for TypeScript in WebStorm; if you miss this feature, please vote for [this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13063).

There are some solutions on the web for this, you can give them a try: [Typescript UML Visualizer](https://github.com/joaompneves/tsviz), [TsUML](https://github.com/remojansen/TsUML), [TypeScript UML Playground](https://tsuml-demo.firebaseapp.com/)